# How to retain dynamically created input fields values if database fails?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a big form around 70 input fields and in the form there are buttons that can create additional input fields. My problem is how do I retain these input fields and their values if something on the server goes wrong upon submitting the form, like database insert failure? I have dynamic validation but what if something goes wrong upon submitting?

Comment: Hmm, as only you know your form best, what do you think? What could be done to deal with that problem? What if you won't destroy the form in the first place until the database operation has been successful? Allowing the user to retry to submit the data in case of failure?

Comment: So, you're trying to say use ajax post?

Comment: I did read your question you were using javascript to build the form dynamically. It's the easiest to turn that into an ajax request then for submission with jquery and that common that I just thought you would do. If you don't do already, I suggest you change that because it is a very simple way to deal with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of options.

1. You could use ajax to post your form, and then redirect to a new page if successful, or alert the user if not (easiest!)
2. You could recreate the from on the server side from the post variables (harder with a complex form)
3. The server could send back the form values on failure, and you can write JS to recreate the form (might be easy if you already have JS to manage the form).
4. You could pass the actual HTML for the form along with the form values, and have the server use it to recreate the form (you may lose JS events depending on how you hook them up, not the best option in general).

There are many more options that are less useful. I would recommend #1.

Comment: I was also thinking doing an ajax post. I think that is the best and easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

**For a really simple solution:**

You can store the values in an object and only once you've got a confirmed DB insert clear it.  If insert fails, and you can retry a few times and it and if fails repeatedly, you can write the values to a CSV log file to handle manually.

**More complex solution**

Queue.  Have all insert requests get queue into a job queue using Zend Jobserver, RabbitMQ or Gearman.  Then create a worker process to run the inserts on the other end of the queue.  This will allow you to re-run /retry failed jobs.

Comment: Is this the best approach do you think?

Comment: @u54r Do you need the values to be available immediately after for the user experience, or is the form just lead/data collection (you don't need to be accessible in absolute real time)?

Comment: if your db commit fails, a retry with the exact same data is unlikely to fix it in most cases. 99% of the time it will be invalid input.

Comment: @levi I agree, but the question asked explicitly indicated 'if database fails'

Comment: @Ray, as one possibility. In my experience, database insert failure during production is more likely to be invalid input (eg, a non-unique value for a unique value column, or a string that is too long without truncation turned on, or a foreign key that was recently deleted)

Comment: @Ray Yes, I want the data to be available immediately after the failure so the user can try it again. It doesn't have to be only db insert failure. I just want to make sure the user doesn't lose any input value.

Comment: @Ray What's the benefit of doing so if I am not going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Why so many fields on a single page? I would reconsider doing this. At any rate, if you have server side validation and it fails you can set up the page to have each field use a default value based on the post value that was sent to the server... So just send them back to the same page and have the input fields value set to the post value.

Here is an example.

```
$username = array(
                            'name'        => 'username',
                            'id'          => 'username',
                            'maxlength'   => '255',
                            'size'        => '28',
                            'title'             => 'username is required.',
                            'class'       => 'form-text required',
                            'value' => $this->input->post('username'),
                          );
<?php echo form_input($username); ?>
```

Comment: The form is used to create a proposal. There are so many variables of the product that is proposed to the customer. I don't think your approach is the best solution because there are multi dimensional arrays and figuring out which is which is cumbersome and overwhelming.

Comment: If you are posting the form and everything has a name all you have to do is grab the form value of the same name and set the value. If it exists, it gets set. If it doesn't exist, it is empty string. The only better solution i can see is the ajaxForm. But this would require a decent sized change to your back end code.

Comment: As I said, there are dynamically created form elements meaning for example name[] can be created over and over again in the form. Your approach is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple of function that you can use to store the form values in a session:

```
    //save form inputs
    function Hold_Form_Input()
        {
        $FormPost = array();
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
                {
                    $FormPost[''.$key.'']= $entry;
                }
         $_SESSION['post_form']= $FormPost;           
        }
    //Clear form values upon success
     function Clear_Form_Input()
        {
           if (isset($_SESSION['post_form']))
               {
                   unset($_SESSION['post_form']);
                 return true;
                }
           return false;
        }

//Reprint form values as needed
    function Keep_on_error($fieldname)
        {
            if(isset($_SESSION['post_form']) && strlen($_SESSION['post_form'][$fieldname]) > 0)
                {
                    $fill = $_SESSION['post_form'][$fieldname];
                    return $fill;
                }
            return false;
        }
```